How to disable a column in a SlickGrid
I want to how can we disable a particular column in Angular Grid.
<angular-slickgrid *ngIf="this.load" gridId="grid1" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="dataset" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($any($event))"
        (onPaginationChanged)="paginationChanged($event)" (onGridStateChanged)="gridStateChanged($any($event))"
        (onBeforeEditCell)="verifyCellIsEditableBeforeEditing($any($event.detail.eventData), $any($event.detail.args))">
    </angular-slickgrid>

Tried this not working
verifyCellIsEditableBeforeEditing(e, args):boolean{
    // your logic here should return true/false if it's editable or not
    // args contains the dataContext and other Slickgrid arguments
    console.log(e,args);
    return false;
  }


You also have to cancel the event bubbling for this to work.
verifyCellIsEditableBeforeEditing(e, args) {
  if (condition) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}

More info in the docs Disabling specific cell edit
